# Matlab Filter design: compact minimum phase filter

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

Suppose we have the following linear system:

[image]

with the transfer function

[image]

and its inverse

[image].

Using Matlab, I would like to design a discrete, compact filter [image] with minimum delay that represents the inverse transfer function, such that

[image],

where I use discrete time-index k to denote that the signals are discrete in time.

I am aware of the Matlab function `invfreqs` and things like `filt` and `filtfilt`, but I don't immediately see how to achieve what I am looking for.